# What's the detail of the instruction "movl ma rb" when ma is DRAM and rb is register

Tags: performance, assembly, cpu

As I know that the **CPU** is 100x faster than the **DRAM**, when execute below instruction

```
movl ma rb //ma is DRAM, rb is register
```

the data is not cached in th LX cache, what happend in cpu?  wait until the data is ready in L1 cache or do some thing else?

Comment: The processor stalls.  It is the job of the prefetcher to not let that happen.

Comment: Modern CPU can execute instructions out of program order. When an instruction is executing and taking a long time, like a cache missed load, the CPU looks forward and tries to find an instruction that can be executed without any data not available yet. If it turns out that no such instruction exists, the CPU stalls until one instruction finish.